# How to capture last exit code from batch file while executing with in powershell script?

Tags: powershell, batch-file

Since batch doesn't have any remoting feature. I was executing a batch file inside Invoke-command script block. But, If the batch file returns %errorlevel% other than 0, How can I capture the value and pass it to powershell to raise execption? I tried by using last two lines of below code and didn't find any luck. As a workaround I have added echo %errorlevel% > C:/out.txt, and from powershell we can read this value and throw an error if it is other than 0. Is there any effective way to achieve this? I have to execute this script in the jenkins. Is there any command in batch equivalent to invoke-command for remoting? Any help would be appreciated.

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock {
param ($server,$source_dir,$processing_dir,$user,$Password)
whoami
echo "$source_dir"
$command="M:\script_test\file1.bat"
cmd /C $Command
$out = cmd /C echo %errorlevel%
echo $out
```

Batch File:
This is my batch command in file1.bat. What changes do I need to make inoder to pass %errorlevel% to $lastexitcode ? This command throws either 1 or 9009 value incase of failure.

```
D:\EDX_CMD\QMSEDX_CommandLine\QMSEDX.exe -task="reload.qvw" -verbosity=5 -password=###### -timeout=800 
echo %errorlevel% > M:\script_test\out.txt
```

Comment: Does your batch file end with `exit /b ##`? Then in powershell you could use `$LastExitCode`.

Comment: If your batch file is echoing the errorlevel of the last command to a text file, why don't you just read the contents of the text file with `GET-CONTENT` in your powershell code?  Otherwise like I said in my first comment, use the command `exit /b %errorlevel%` instead of echoing the errorlevel to a file. Then use `$LastExitCode` in your Powershell.

Comment: Is executing `QMSEDX` the only command that the batch file runs?  If so, why don't you just put it in your Powershell script and then use `$LastExitCode`?

Comment: for some reason this command is only working with cmd,exe, If I try this with the powershell it was throwing me following error 
 D:\Program Files\EDX_CMD\QMSEDX_CommandLine\QMSEDX.exe -task="Reload.qvw <<<< " -verbosity=5
-password=##### -timeout=800. I was able to solve issue by placing `exit /b %errorlevel%` in bat file. Thank you

Comment: I would assume it is throwing an error because the path to the program has a space in it. So you should put quotes around the whole path and file name.

Comment: I did it but still its throwing me same error. I believe `QMSEDX` does support only as batch command.

Comment: Doubtful.  You should be able launch any Windows Executable from batch, powershell, vbscript and even jscript as far as Windows based scripting languages go.  I am not really seeing the error in your comment. All I see is the code. You should put that kind of information in your question by editing it because it is very hard to read code in comments.